# How to block this memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have narrowed my programs memory leak down to one of these dynamically created content. The leak is very very small and causes no problems but it would be best to be fixed, here is the code:

```
//allocate row memory:
dynamicNodeArray = new int *[r];
//allocate column memory:
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    dynamicNodeArray[i] = new int[c];
}

//...

//allocate memory for nodes (array of structs):
node* nodes = new node[r*c];

//...

//clean up:
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
    delete dynamicNodeArray[i];
}

delete dynamicNodeArray;
free(nodes);
delete nodes;
```

Comment: Besides the misspellings, why on earth is there a `free` of memory allocated by `new`? (and `new[]` should have corresponding `delete[]`)

Comment: To delete an array, use delete[]. Is there any problem using std::vector instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete dynamicNodeArray;` should be `delete [] dynamicNodeArray;` as you allocated it with `new[]`.

Also never call `free()` on stuff you have allocated with `new()` or `new[]`.

Comment: I did what you suggested, fixed the prob here atleast I believe.